# separate angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am exploring angular directives. I have created 2 simple ones following this example taken from

http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/11/28/create-resusable-angularjs-input-component/

```
angular.module('demo', [])

.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.rating = 42;      
})

.directive('rnStepper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            value: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="decrement()">-</button>' +
                  '<div>{{ value }}</div>' +
                  '<button ng-click="increment()">+</button>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.increment = function() {
                scope.value++;
            }
            scope.decrement = function() {
                scope.value--;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This is contained in my app.js file: ../app/scripts/app.js

Now I would like to move the directive code in a separate file in the following folder:

../app/custom_directive/my_demo_directive.js

```
.directive('rnStepper', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                value: '=ngModel'
            },
            template: '<button ng-click="decrement()">-</button>' +
                      '<div>{{ value }}</div>' +
                      '<button ng-click="increment()">+</button>',
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                scope.increment = function() {
                    scope.value++;
                }
                scope.decrement = function() {
                    scope.value--;
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

how do I export the directive from the new location and how I do modified the directive declaration in the app.js file?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just remove the directive declaration from app.js, and put it in the other file that way:

```
angular.module('demo').directive('rnStepper', function() {
    // same as before
});
```

Note that `angular.module()` is called with a single argument, which means that you want to get a reference to a previously defined module named 'demo' (whereas, when called with an array as second argument, `angular.module()` defines a new module).

Also note that, since the module must have been defined previously, app.js must come before the directive js file in the list of `<script>` elements in the HTML file.

Comment: Many thanks for the description. I was keep hitting my head until I read your answer.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is copy the module declaration to the new file along with moving the directive (make sure you leave the module declaration in the controller still).  So in one file, you will have `angular.module('demo', []).controller(...)` and in the other, you will have `angular.module('demo').directive(...)`.  Since it is still in the same module, you won't need to change app.js, but you will need to make sure to pull the new file into your index.html.

If you are also wanting the directive to be in a different module, then you would need to add the new module to your app.js file.

Comment: This is wrong: it will redefine the demo module, effectively replacing the old one, containing the controller, with a new one, containing **only** the directive.

Comment: @JB Whoops!  Copied the code and forgot to take out the [] in the module declaration.  You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Move the directive code into a separate file like in the following example, add it to your html document as a script and you are good to go.

```
angular.module('demo')
.directive('directiveName', function() {
    ...
});
```